# C. Ok in main but segmentation fault when inside function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This piece of code gives a segmentation fault but If the test function body in written directly in the main function it works properly. So, what do you think is causing this problem?

Segmentation fault:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int test()
{
    int i=0;
    int *p;
    printf("pass\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        *(p+i) = i;
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
    }
    return 1;

}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    x = test();
}
```

Working fine:

```
int main() {
    int i=0;
    int *p;
    printf("pass\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        *(p+i) = i;
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Before throwing me with a bunch of down votes, please try the code. I know it is bad programming. I'm evaluating some C code exames and had a student that wrote this. Yes, not very good, but is a fact that the working version is actually working.

Comment: `x = teste();` shouldn't that be `test`? Typo? Also, working with memory that isn't assigned or allocated, and then wondering why it faults?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined

Comment: *Neither* version actually works. Where does the pointer `p` point?

Comment: @AntonH it is a typo.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, have you tried it?

Comment: How can you dereference a pointer that doesn't point to anything? Even more, how dare you advance the pointer and dereference it with `*(p+i)`? __This pointer points to nowhere__, to memory potentially not owned by your process. This is what causes a segfault. This can also work fine as this is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't need to "try it" because uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value. If such a variable is a pointer, and you dereference it, you *will* have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you have UB then that makes you whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: Undefined behaviour in both cases.

Comment: As for *why* it *seems* to be working, that depends on your compiler, your target system, your host system, and possibly the time of day and the moon phase. No one can expect to reliably replicate the "working" behavior of UB. If that is indeed a student that gave you the code then I would give the student a failing grade immediately.

Comment: Uhmm... if you are evaluating some C code exams, shouldn't you know about _undefined dbehaviour_?

Comment: Ah, the question! Have you notice that the question is about something that was not supposed to be working?

Comment: @Miguel-- you seem to be confused about undefined behavior. Undefined behavior may include working as expected. Changing one seemingly unrelated line of code may cause the code to fail. The answer to the question, "So, what do you think is causing this problem?" is, both code samples contain undefined behavior, and are thus not well-formed, valid C programs.

Comment: You should note that a car travelling efficiently down the highway at 100kph may well be described as 'working correctly', even though it has a time bomb in the trunk.

Answer (score 7):

The `p` pointer is not initialized in both cases. It contains an undetermined value.

Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is **undefined behaviour** (google that).

In the first case your pointer `p` happens  by chance to point somewhere where the dereferencement does not end up in a segfault (that is valid memory that your process is allowed to read), but in the second case it points to another location where dereferencement *does* end up in a segfault (dereferencement of memory that your process is *not* allowed to read).

Comment: @Miguel it "works" by _chance_. For example on my computer both examples segfault.

Comment: @Miguel you had luck and your uninitialized pointer pointed to some *by luck* valid location for your program.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Even so it is quite strange. It can't be only a matter of luck.

Comment: @Miguel of course it is a matter of luck. It's _undefined behaviour_. Roughly spoken: undefined behaviour ranges from "resetting your computer" to "apparently working fine".

Comment: @Miguel-- if you are evaluating exam code in C, you had better learn about undefined behavior. [Here is a convenient summary from the C11 Draft Standard.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)

Comment: @DavidBowling, have you notice that the question was not about that undefined behavior? And that I haven't still see an answer from you, experts (sorry, but luck is not enough...).

Comment: @Miguel IMHO my answer perfectly answers your question. Please explain what is not clear in my answer and I'd be happy to improve it.

Comment: Because it does not explains why the second example is working when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Miguelbut it **does** explain it. The uninitialized values are **not** the same in both cases, and with the program compiled with _your_ particular compiler on _your_ particular computer it happens that the value of `p` in `main` is by chance a memory address that your process is allowed to read. This memory address is probably a leftover from the initialisation code (that is the code that calls `main`). Add following line before `printf("%d\n",*(p+i)); `: `printf("Address: %p\n",(void*)(p+i));`, which will printout the actual address.

Comment: @Miguel Invoking undefined behavior does not guarantee a crash.   It might crash, it might output unexpected results, or it might appear to work properly.  Subsequently making a seemingly unrelated change, such as adding a `printf` for debugging, adding an unused local variable, or (in your case) moving code into a function can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.  Another example: on my machine the second piece of code appears to work fine if I compile without optimizations but crashes if I compile with optimizations.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and remaining fellow experts. Thank you all for such welcome reception. It is very nice to rely with such a friendly community! With such down votes I can only conclude that my question is not worth you wiseness, and therefore I shall delete it, so that no other human may read such nonsenses. Thank you all!

Comment: @Miguel The fact that everybody puts comments and trys to explain, shows that the question *is* welcome, even if it has been downvoted (not by me btw).

Comment: Yes, but only these last comments. These are genuine answers!

Comment: @Miguel and nobody insulted anybody here btw. People simply insisted on the concept of _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: Well, more or less. Anyways, thanks. I won't delete it.

Comment: To be pedantic, if the app produces the expected output, it's BAD luck - you might deliver the app to 10,000 customers before you find out its behaviour is undefined.